# central and non-central chi square distribution in one plot with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

What I want is to draw a chi square distribution - both a central and non-central into one plot and draw parts of the surface underneath as solid color.

Note: I read [Plotting the chi square distribution with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40908/plotting-the-chi-square-distribution-with-tikz) but none of the solutions allows drawing a **non-central**chi square distribution

Comment: I do not find any question in your post. What have you tried, where do you fail? Where is the code we can start with? And personally: I do not know by head what a non-central chi square distribution is. You should make that clear by an image or give us the formula which shall be plotted. Please show some own effort as this site is not about getting work done by others. Thank you.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi - See the entry [Noncentral chi-squared distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) at Wikipedia. :-)

Comment: Re the earlier posting you've cited: It employs the formula for the probability density function (pdf) of *central* chi-squared distributions. Are you having a problem adapting this code to plot the pdfs of non-central chi-squared distributions? The closed-form expression of a non-central chi-squared distribution is very similar to that of a central chi-squared distribution...

Comment: It looks like `gnuplot` cannot plot Modified Bessel functions of first kind so you'll have to use an external tool to compute the points and plot them with `TiKZ` or `pgfplots`.

Comment: That is exactly my issue, gnuplot is too dumb, and I did not find a method of pgffoo that provides non central chi square distribution. Also there is no closed form of a non-central chi squared distribution, only a sum of infinite number of weighted chi squared distributions. So I do not have an idea if I can do this directly in tex or if I have to fallback to R which I am not familiar with at all.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi if I posted an image, that would a blunt copy of wikipedia and unnecessary if you knew chi squared distribution. And the difficulty is to specifically plot the non-central chi squared pdf, not the plotting of a function itself.