# plot and annotate chi square distribution

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, statistics

My question is replacing Gaussian distribution with chi square distribution in following codes. So it should show a chi-square distribution instead of a normal distribution. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
\pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 no markers, domain=0:8, samples=100,
 axis y line = none,
 axis x line* = bottom,
 every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
 height=5cm, width=12cm,
 xtick={2.5,5.5}, xticklabels = {$$ , $$}, ytick=\empty,
 enlargelimits=false, clip=false, axis on top,
 grid = major
 ]
 \addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=0:2.5] {gauss(4,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot [fill=cyan!20, draw=none, domain=5.5:8] {gauss(4,1)} \closedcycle;
\addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(4,1)};

\draw [yshift=-0.3cm, latex-latex](axis cs:4,0) -- node [fill=white] {$0.35$} 
(axis cs:4,0);

\draw [yshift=+2cm, latex-latex](axis cs:2.5,0) -- node [fill=white] {$H_0$ 
Do not Reject} (axis cs:5.5,0);

\draw [yshift=+2cm, latex-latex](axis cs:0,0) -- node [fill=white] {$H_0$ 
Reject} (axis cs:2.5,0);

\draw [yshift=+2cm, latex-latex](axis cs:5.5,0) -- node [fill=white] {$H_0$ 
Reject} (axis cs:8,0);
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No it is not a duplication. I cannot change gauss function in codes with a new function which can be called as chisquare. Because chi square has gamma function and I am not so good at functions in latex. any help will be appreciated

Comment: I still think this is a duplicate. You seem to be right that the Gamma function cannot be easily written in LaTeX, that is why the first given solution in the aforementioned question shows a solution to this problem, when you have gnuplot installed, and the third solution shows an approximated solution using pure TikZ.

Comment: Stefan thanks for your comment. However I still need help. I even cannot change the loop in the aforementioned question to a single distribution plot.

Comment: Then I recommend asking a [follow-up questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117). Include a link to the answer from where you "copied" the code from and state what you have tried so far. Then chances are high, that someone will help you. (Since your question now will be about pgfplots, please add this as a tag.)

Comment: @StefanPinnow Well this is a follow up what else is needed?

Comment: @MehmetOZC Can you state your question clearly such that the problem is precisely described including loops or math functions or colors or whatever you need to fix from that duplicate

Comment: First of all I have really copied the codes in my question many years ago from another code which is probably published in this platform and I am grateful to he\she\them. I am trying to clarify the problem. You can see a predefined function in the preamble of the code which is called as gauss and has two inputs with (\pgfmathdeclarefunction). I want to replace it with a new function which calculates chi square.

Comment: Yes but what is it? What is the problem? Why is it not possible with the duplicate?  This is not a math site so people don't know necessarily what you mean by that.

Comment: @percusse, for me it would be a follow-up question if OP would have included the "duplicate" question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40908/95441 and (in addition) would have stated that it is **required** to have a solution which uses `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`. In its current form I stick to it, that it is a duplicate. ([Herbert's solution below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409095/95441) by the way is (almost) exactly the same as [his answer to the "duplicate" question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40922/95441)...)

Comment: @StefanPinnow In any case **1 hour** is in no way appropriate to close the question without consulting the OP and people can have difficulty formulating questions. But still, I agree with the rest of your remark.

Comment: @percusse, I agree that people can have difficulties on formulating questions, but I still think it is ok to start a close-vote. It is still possible to comment below the (closed) question and to edit it, which is then reviewed and can be opened again. So this is most likely opinion-based ...

Comment: No need to say but I'm new. I have asked a new question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409124/plotting-chi-square-hypothesis-testing-regions which shows a figure about the question. I planned to delete the question but I did not find any delete button. A moderator can close or even delete the question. It is not a problem for me.

Comment: @MehmetOZC, there should be a delete button at the very end of the question, directly before the comments start.

Comment: I cannot delete it

Comment: No, it's not possible to delete questions that have gotten upvoted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pretty code, but it works. The chi-square plotting is from cjorssen's answer to [Plotting the chi square distribution with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40908).

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
    restrict y to domain = 0:0.5,
    xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
    axis lines*=left,
    hide y axis,
    clip=false,
    width=8cm,
    height=4cm
]

   \addplot+[name path=chi,mark={}] gnuplot[raw gnuplot] {%
        isint(x) = (int(x)==x);
        log2 = 0.693147180559945;
        chisq(x,k)=k<=0||!isint(k)?1/0:x<=0?0.0:exp((0.5*k-1.0)*log(x)-0.5*x-lgamma(0.5*k)-k*0.5*log2);
        set xrange [1.00000e-5:15.0000];
        set yrange [0.00000:0.500000];
        samples=200;
        plot chisq(x,4)};

   \path [name path=xax] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) 
                      -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin});

   \addplot [fill=blue!30] fill between[of=chi and xax, soft clip={domain=10:15}];

   \draw (10, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}) -- (10, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}-0.05)
         node[below,font=\footnotesize] {$\chi^2=2.547$};

   \draw [stealth-] (13.5, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (13.5, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}-0.1)
         node[below,font=\footnotesize] {Calculated $\chi^2=5.147$};

   \draw [stealth-, shorten >=2pt] (rel axis cs:0,0.5) -- node[fill=white,font=\scriptsize]{Not rejecting of $H_0$} (10,0 |- {rel axis cs:0,0.5});

   \draw [-stealth, shorten <=2pt] (10,0 |- {rel axis cs:0,0.5}) -- node[fill=white,align=center,font=\scriptsize]{Rejecting\\region\\of $H_0$} (rel axis cs:1,0.5);

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is pretty. However I got an error ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, 'compat=1.15' is unknown in this context. Plea
se use at most 'compat=1.14'.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be fitted better at "[the other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409124/95441)"?

Comment: @MehmetOZC So do what the error says, and  change `compat=1.15` to `compat=1.14`. I have version 1.15 of `pgfplots`, you seem to have version 1.14.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Maybe, maybe not.

Answer (score 4):

Run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func}  
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=1.2cm,yunit=10cm,plotpoints=200}
\begin{pspicture*}(-0.75,-0.1)(10,0.65)
    \multido{\rnue=0.5+0.5,\iblue=0+10}{10}{%
        \psChiIIDist[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=blue!\iblue,nue=\rnue]{0.01}{9}}
    \psaxes[Dy=0.1]{->}(0,0)(9.5,.6)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Herbert thanks for your answer. It really produces chi square. It is in your previous post and I have work on it. However it is a pspicture. In my project I work with tikzpicture. Is it possible to write codes in tikzpicture instead of pspicture? Also I need a single distribution. In your code, it produces 10 distribution in the same figure.

Comment: I always use PSTricks. Instead of `\multido`  use only one `\psChiIIDist`. Then you'll get only one distribution